# How to set an estimated position without using rviz

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my project, I want to use multiple turtlebots to navigate in a previously known map to patrol an area.
My netbooks uses 2GB of RAM and an Atom N455 processor - it is not so good as D525, but i think it could make some things on ROS...
I noticed that rviz and another graphic processes requires a lot of processing and video resources, so I want to avoid using rviz and those processes, because I don't need graphical resources.
But how can I set a estimated position of the robots without using rviz?
And do you believe that my current netbook (Atom N455 and 2GB RAM) can support an autonomous navigation?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11396/how-to-set-an-estimated-position-without-using-rviz/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-10-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try using one of the lightweight rviz alternatives for machines with little graphics power. Those can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_view).

Additionally, you could create your own `initialpose` message and publish it to amcl that way (if you know the robot's pose). The `initialpose` message is of the type [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html).

**EDIT**: For this message type, the `seq` field is filled in by ROS automatically, and the stamp is zero, so you can ignore both of those fields. The `frame_id` is /base_link. Finally, the covariance is a 6x6 matrix that is filled in with set values. I've provided an example message below that was taken straight from Rviz.

```
header: 
  seq: 14
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -5.48213577271
      y: -3.74665260315
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.457581479883
      w: 0.889167694683
  covariance: [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-04**:
the xyzw is quaternion notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-10-04**:
Thanks again! W is the scalar part, isn't? And is the covariance matrix filled by ROS? Or should I always use those values?

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-10-03**:
I really appreciate your help! But... how can I use that message type? I did not understood what should I use in covariance, seq, stamp and frame_id...  And which node does the position of the robot is published?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, people don't run rviz on the computers on their robots. Instead, they use another laptop/desktop computer and set the environment variable ROS_MASTER_URI to the robot before running rviz. Example:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://turtlebot1:11311
rosrun rviz rviz
```

In the above example, the robot has the domain turtlebot1. You can also just use an ip address there or set up your hosts file as explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

If you really need an alternative to rviz, see DimitriProsser's answer.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4